# aligning text in the center inside the div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been trying to style a Register form. I want the heading to be in the center of the div. I have another login form just beside it.

I have styled them using flex box and then used justify content as center. I also want to add a vertical line between the register form and login form. I don't want to use one of the borders of the form. Apart from using one of the form's border is there any way to do it.

> Things I've tried but didn't work
>
> 1.`text-align: center`:
>
> 2.`margin: 0 auto;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#head {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, cyan, purple);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
}

#head h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}

input [name="register"] {
  background-color: green;
}

#login {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}

#login h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#register {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Joint.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes|Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="head">
    <h1>The Joint.</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="whtpg">
    <div class="cont">
      <div id="register">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <form action="reglog.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
          <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username"><br>
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="login">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <form action="reglog.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username"><br>
          <input type="password" name="lpass" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: post html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For centering the heading of the register form, use:

```css
#register h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

And similarly, for centering the heading of the login form, use:

```css
#login h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

And, for the vertical line, create an empty `div` and style it. I've used `divider` class here:

```css
.divider {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

See the full code below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#head {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, cyan, purple);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
}

#head h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}

input [name="register"] {
  background-color: green;
}

#login {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}

#login h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#register {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}

#register h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.divider {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Joint.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes|Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="head">
    <h1>The Joint.</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="whtpg">
    <div class="cont">
      <div id="register">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <form action="reglog.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
          <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username"><br>
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div id="login">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <form action="reglog.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username"><br>
          <input type="password" name="lpass" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @TheWIseone Maybe, this is what you wanted :)

Comment: Thanks SIr..! It was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could post the html and css.

My guess is that the container div has no width settings, so the div is the same width as the text, so you cannot center it. Maybe set the width to 100% of its container and set the text-align to center and see if that helps.

From your code you could try

```
#register h3 {
    text-align:center;
}
```

this will mean any h3 tags inside the div with the id register will have the text-align:center attribute applied to them

Otherwise post the HTML and CSS and we can take a look. (I see the HTML now, add the CSS too please

Comment: I have added the code, Sorry it took time, the website kept saying that I have to add more text as my question was full of code.

Comment: Yes I can see that you have no width params in your css, because you have no width params it is rather difficult for the css to center align text. You need to add width params to these elements so: `#register h3 {
    text-align:center; width:200px;
}` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

you can draw a line in the middle using CSS pseudo selector`::after` following is the piece of CSS rule to do that.

```
div#register::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 50%;
}
.cont h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
  body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#head {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, cyan, purple);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
}

#head h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}

input [name="register"] {
  background-color: green;
}

#login {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}

#login h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#register {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}

div#register::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 50%;
}
.cont h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Joint.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes|Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="head">
    <h1>The Joint.</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="whtpg">
    <div class="cont">
      <div id="register">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <form action="reglog.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
          <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username"><br>
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="login">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <form action="reglog.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username"><br>
          <input type="password" name="lpass" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```